# File Upload:Trim-last-few-Characters-Save Extension

Tags: python, django, file-upload

My model allows uploaded 'filenames' to be of size up to 255 characters. If its more than that it crashes. What I need in place is "something like ellipsis i.e. three dots (...) after some 225 characters and then 'display the extension' of the file."

This is a little code in my models file, which I feel is the point of Impact:

```
class Attachment(models.Model):
file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, max_length=256,
        storage=AttachmentsStorage() if AttachmentsStorage else None)
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything already? We can help you much better if you show what you've come up with so far.

Comment: The question is will the information in this field be needed later on?

Comment: @bcelary Ideally if the information is stil available, when needed, after adding ellipsis, well and good.. otherwise also its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`os.path.splitext()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) to split off the extension:

```
if len(path) > 255:
    path, ext = os.path.split(path)
    path = path[:252-len(ext)] + '...' + ext
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a good way to solve your problem is to overload method [`AttachmentsStorage. get_valid_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-file-storage/#get-valid-name-name), which is responsible for converting the file names.